# CSS last-child on HTML5 article

Tags: wordpress, css, css-selectors

In my blog, I have a series of HTML5 articles like so:

```
<div id="blog">
<article class="post">  
    <div class="blogLeft">
        <img src="images/5.jpg" />          
    </div>

    <div class="blogRight">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut laoreet, ligula in commodo vestibulum, erat purus consectetur ipsum, ac sodales quam risus id nibh. Suspendisse iaculis egestas nisi et pharetra. Proin gravida, eros et aliquam tempus, massa diam feugiat urna, vestibulum suscipit purus diam vitae turpis. Cras congue aliquet sollicitudin. Fusce sit amet dui odio. In vitae dictum ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <a class="readMore" href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
</article>

....this article repeats 7 times
</div>
```

I want to use css selector, last-child to select the last article and remove the bottom border. Normally I would use `article.post:last-child{margin-bottom:0; padding:0; border-bottom:0}` but for some reason this isnt selecting the last article. Any idea what I am doing wrong? It works great if I was to use an unordered list, but not so much with articles.

Comment: It [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/m6aJR/), in Firefox/Win XP.

Comment: not working for me for whatever reason...

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using, then? Edit: and version of browser

Comment: Use your developer tool to check what children `#blog` has. If the very last child is not `article.post`, there's the problem.

Comment: not working in any of the modern browsers on mac, chrome firefox, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just personal preference, but try defining your parent within the selector:

```
#blog article.post:last-child
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/wjCTx/

Also, instead of:

```
<div id="blog">
```

I think using a Section tag may be more semantic.

Comment: Perhaps it's a browser issue? Are you in IE?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old problem, but I was having the same issues and came across this.

The above won't work if you have anything after the *article* tags (i.e. where you typed "....this article repeats 7 times") If there's anything after the article tags (a footer for instance), then the last article is *not* the last-child of its parent.

This selector worked for me (Windows 8, Chrome):

```
article:last-of-type{}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaco79/52M54/1/) and try removing the header and footer HTML tags to see the difference between :last-child and :last-of-type

Answer (score 1):

You could try this?

```
article.post div:last-child{}​
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wFByK/) fiddle.

e: I couldn't get it to work either, if I was just using `article.post:last-child`

Comment: that isnt how my HTML is set up. Each blog post is an article, not them as a whole